# Divergence of first Piola-Kirchoff stress tensor

Tags: coordinate-systems, tensor-calculus, continuum-mechanics, stress-strain

I'm studying elasticity theory and for the problem "Finite Bending of an incompressible elastic block" I have the following first Piola-Kirchoff stress tensor:

$$S=\left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_1} + \mu_0 \lambda_1\!\right)e_r \otimes e_1 + \left(\frac{\pi + \mu_0}{\lambda_2} + \mu_0 \lambda_2\!\right) e_\theta \otimes e_2$$

where $e_r = cos(\theta) e_1 + \sin(\theta) e_2$ and $e_\theta = - \sin(\theta) e_1 + \cos(\theta) e_2$

The author writes ([see here at page 186 formula (5.95)](https://books.google.it/books?id=f3RrYLujw8oC&pg=PA179&lpg=PA179&dq=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&source=bl&ots=hDKzQSjxSv&sig=ACfU3U3fLyBQ9a3XuAl14bfvVHTrmfKs6Q&hl=it&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi61bzqxLfwAhVGi6QKHcWEBt8Q6AEwCXoECAUQAw#v=onepage&q=Finite%20bending%20of%20an%20incompressible%20elastic%20block&f=false)):

$$Div(S) = \frac{\partial }{\partial x_1^0} S_{r1} e_r + \frac{\partial}{\partial x_2^0} S_{\theta 2} e_{\theta} = 0$$

but **I can't understand what are the steps to get this result**.

I mean, I know that in cartesian coordinates the divergence of a tensor $S$ is defined as $(Div(S))_i = S_{ij,j}$ but I don't know why he wrote that expression with $e_r$ and $e_\theta$. How can I compute that divergence? What are the steps I have to do?

Comment: My guess is that the derivative applies to both the stress component and the unit vector. In that case, it is correct.

Comment: Could you be more explicit? I'm not following you in your first sentence. @nicoguaro

Comment: The derivative of unit vectors is not zero for coordinates different from Cartesian. That is,

$$\frac{\partial \hat{\mathbf{e}}_r}{\partial x_1} \neq 0\, .$$

Comment: @nicoguaro I'm sorry, but I don't know where I should apply that fact. Could you please show how this must be used?

Comment: You have a product $S_{r1}\hat{\mathbf{e}}_r$, if you take a derivative you need to use the derivative of a product that includes a derivative of the unit vector.

Comment: Ouch, so it is $\frac{\partial }{\partial x_1^0} (S_{r1} e_r)$, I see. Then my ultimate question is: why do you differentiate w.r.t $x_1,x_2$ and not w.r.t. $e_r, e_{\theta}$ when you compute the divergence? @nicoguaro

Comment: That won't make the derivatives to be 0, so you still have the same problem. Now, I have not read that book to tell you why it is this way. Also, the first Piola-Kirchhoff is not used that much since it involves normal vectors in one frame and forces in another frame.

Comment: @nicoguaro Yes indeed this is really what is confusing me, i.e. the fact it's a "2 point" tensor